# Powershell Get-Volumn for remote computer

Tags: powershell

Below is the code I am executing for my local server to get the disk details

```
$props = @(
    'DriveLetter'
    'FileSystemLabel'
    'FileSystem'
    'DriveType'
    'HealthStatus'
    'OperationalStatus'
    @{n='SizeRemaining';e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining/ 1Gb)}}
    @{n='Size';e={"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size / 1Gb)}}
    @{n='% Free';e={"{0:P}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining / $_.Size)}}
)

$Diskmgmt = Get-Volume | Select-Object $props 


foreach($dsk in $Diskmgmt)
{

    $dl = $dsk.DriveLetter
    $fsl = $dsk.FileSystemLabel
    $fs = $dsk.FileSystem
    $dt = $dsk.DriveType
    $hs = $dsk.HealthStatus
    $os = $dsk.OperationalStatus
    $sizer = $dsk.SizeRemaining
    $siz = $dsk.Size
    $PercentFree = $dsk.'% Free'
}
```

I need to connect to remote server and get the data.

Please let me know how to connect remote computer for this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Volume` also has a parameter `CimSession` where you can give it a computername or an array of computernames. (*Runs the cmdlet in a remote session or on a remote computer. Enter a computer name or a session object*)

This lets you simplify your code to:

```
$props = @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.PSComputerName}},
         'DriveLetter','FileSystemLabel','FileSystem','DriveType','HealthStatus','OperationalStatus',
         @{Name = 'SizeRemaining_GB'; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining/ 1Gb)}},
         @{Name = 'Size_GB'; Expression = {"{0:N2}" -f ($_.Size / 1Gb)}},
         @{Name = '% Free'; Expression = {"{0:P}" -f ($_.SizeRemaining / $_.Size)}}

$Diskmgmt = Get-Volume -CimSession server01, server02 | Select-Object $props | Sort-Object ComputerName, DriveLetter
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the Microsoft docs on running remote commands:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.2

It looks like it may just be as simple as making sure remote execution is enabled on the target computer and then running something like this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01, Server02 -ScriptBlock {Get-UICulture}
```

Or if you want to do it interactively, you can connect/disconnect using `Enter-PSSession ServerName` and `Exit-PSSession` which are also explained more in detail in the above documentation.

Edit:

You may also want to look into remote variables:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.2

Basically when you are executing that script block it does not have access to any local variables defined outside of that block unless you explicitly access them using the `$using:myVariable` sytanx.